# Python Pandas: Find index based on value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to specify a DataFrame index (row) based on matching text inside the dataframe?

I am importing a text file from the internet located [here](http://oasis.pjm.com/doc/projload.txt) every day into a python pandas DataFrame.  I am parsing out just some of the data and doing calculations to give me the peak value for each day.  The specific group of data I am needing to gather starts with the section headed "RTO COMBINED HOUR ENDING INTEGRATED FORECAST LOAD MW".

I need to specifically only use part of the data to do the calculations I need and I am able to manually specify which index line to start with, but daily this number could change due to text added to the top of the file by the authors.

> Updated as of: 05-05-2016 1700 Constrained operations ARE expected in
>   the AEP, APS, BC, COMED, DOM,and PS zones on 05-06-2016. Constrained
>   operations ARE expected in the AEP, APS, BC, COMED, DOM,and PS zones
>   on 05-07-2016. The PS/ConEd 600/400 MW contract will be limited to
>   700MW on 05-06-16.

Is there a way to match text in the pandas DataFrame and specify the index of that match?  Currently I am manually specifying the index I want to start with using the variable '**day**' below on the 6th line.  I would like this variable to hold the index (row) of the dataframe that includes the text I want to match.

The code below works but may stop working if the line number (index) changes:

```
def forecastload():
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'pjmactualload.xlsx')
    ws = wb['PJM Load']    
    printRow = 13
    #put this in iteration to pull 2 rows of data at a time (one for each day) for 7 days max
    day = 239
    while day < 251:
        #pulls in first day only
        data = pd.read_csv("http://oasis.pjm.com/doc/projload.txt", skiprows=day, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, nrows=2)

        #sets data at HE 24 = to data that is in HE 13- so I can delete column 0 data to allow checking 'max'
        data.at[1,13]= data.at[1,1]

        #get date for printing it with max load later on
        newDate = str(data.at[0,0])

        #now delete first column to get rid of date data.  date already saved as newDate
        data = data.drop(0,1)
        data = data.drop(1,1)

        #pull out max value of day
        #add index to this for iteration ie dayMax[x] = data.values.max()
        dayMax = data.max().max()
        dayMin = data.min().min()
        #print date and max load for that date
        actualMax = "Forecast Max"
        actualMin = "Forecast Min"
        dayMax = int(dayMax)
        maxResults = [str(newDate),int(dayMax),actualMax,dayMin,actualMin]
        d = 1
        for items in maxResults:
            ws.cell(row=printRow, column=d).value = items
            d += 1        
        printRow += 1        
        #print maxResults
        #l.writerows(maxResults)    
        day = day + 2
    wb.save('pjmactualload.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case i recommend you to use the command line in order to obtain a dataset that you could read later with `pandas` and do whatever you want.

To retrieve the data you can use `curl` and `grep`:

```
$ curl -s http://oasis.pjm.com/doc/projload.txt | grep -A 17 "RTO COMBINED HOUR ENDING INTEGRATED FORECAST" | tail -n +5
 05/06/16 am   68640   66576   65295   65170   66106   70770   77926   83048   84949   85756   86131   86089
          pm   85418   85285   84579   83762   83562   83289   82451   82460   84009   82771   78420   73258
 05/07/16 am   66809   63994   62420   61640   61848   63403   65736   68489   71850   74183   75403   75529
          pm   75186   74613   74072   73950   74386   74978   75135   75585   77414   76451   72529   67957
 05/08/16 am   63583   60903   59317   58492   58421   59378   60780   62971   66289   68997   70436   71212
          pm   71774   71841   71635   71831   72605   73876   74619   75848   78338   77121   72665   67763
 05/09/16 am   63865   61729   60669   60651   62175   66796   74620   79930   81978   83140   84307   84778
          pm   85112   85562   85568   85484   85766   85924   85487   85737   87366   84987   78666   72166
 05/10/16 am   67581   64686   62968   62364   63400   67603   75311   80515   82655   84252   86078   87120
          pm   88021   88990   89311   89477   89752   89860   89256   89327   90469   87730   81220   74449
 05/11/16 am   70367   67044   65125   64265   65054   69060   76424   81785   84646   87097   89541   91276
          pm   92646   93906   94593   94970   95321   95073   93897   93162   93615   90974   84335   77172
 05/12/16 am   71345   67840   65837   64892   65600   69547   76853   82077   84796   87053   89135   90527
          pm   91495   92351   92583   92473   92541   92053   90818   90241   90750   88135   81816   75042
```

Let's use the previous output (in the `rto.txt` file) to obtain a more readable data using `awk` and `sed`:

```
$ awk '/^ [0-9]/{d=$1;print $0;next}{print d,$0}' rto.txt | sed 's/^ //;s/\s\+/,/g'
05/06/16,am,68640,66576,65295,65170,66106,70770,77926,83048,84949,85756,86131,86089
05/06/16,pm,85418,85285,84579,83762,83562,83289,82451,82460,84009,82771,78420,73258
05/07/16,am,66809,63994,62420,61640,61848,63403,65736,68489,71850,74183,75403,75529
05/07/16,pm,75186,74613,74072,73950,74386,74978,75135,75585,77414,76451,72529,67957
05/08/16,am,63583,60903,59317,58492,58421,59378,60780,62971,66289,68997,70436,71212
05/08/16,pm,71774,71841,71635,71831,72605,73876,74619,75848,78338,77121,72665,67763
05/09/16,am,63865,61729,60669,60651,62175,66796,74620,79930,81978,83140,84307,84778
05/09/16,pm,85112,85562,85568,85484,85766,85924,85487,85737,87366,84987,78666,72166
05/10/16,am,67581,64686,62968,62364,63400,67603,75311,80515,82655,84252,86078,87120
05/10/16,pm,88021,88990,89311,89477,89752,89860,89256,89327,90469,87730,81220,74449
05/11/16,am,70367,67044,65125,64265,65054,69060,76424,81785,84646,87097,89541,91276
05/11/16,pm,92646,93906,94593,94970,95321,95073,93897,93162,93615,90974,84335,77172
05/12/16,am,71345,67840,65837,64892,65600,69547,76853,82077,84796,87053,89135,90527
05/12/16,pm,91495,92351,92583,92473,92541,92053,90818,90241,90750,88135,81816,75042
```

now, read and reshape the above result with `pandas`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("rto2.txt",names=["date","period"]+list(range(1,13)),index_col=[0,1])
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_2":"hour",0:"value"})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x: "{date} {hour}:00 {period}".format(**x),axis=1))
df.drop(["date", "hour", "period"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

At this point you have a beautiful time series :)

```
In [10]: df.head()
Out[10]: 
                     value
2016-05-06 01:00:00  68640
2016-05-06 02:00:00  66576
2016-05-06 03:00:00  65295
2016-05-06 04:00:00  65170
2016-05-06 05:00:00  66106
```

to obtain the statistics:

```
In[11]: df.groupby(df.index.date).agg([min,max])
Out[11]: 
            value       
              min    max
2016-05-06  65170  86131
2016-05-07  61640  77414
2016-05-08  58421  78338
2016-05-09  60651  87366
2016-05-10  62364  90469
2016-05-11  64265  95321
2016-05-12  64892  92583
```

I hope this can help you.

Regards.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  This is the kind of output I was shooting for but had no idea how to get there.  I've only heard of sed and awk and will be spending some time with them this weekend.  Thanks again.

Comment: As I go through this, the following line is throwing an error when I run: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x: "{date} {hour}:00 {period}".format(**x),axis=1))`    The error is: `KeyError: ('date', u'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: You're welcome. The command line is a very powerful tool and often provide the simplest solution. Oh, what kind of error you got?

Comment: Perhaps is your pandas version, I have 0.18, could you try using (**x.to_dict()) in the format argument? This line form the datetime index

Comment: anyway, there exist other manners to do that, for example using strings concatenation df["date"]+" "+df ["hour"].apply(str)+":00 "+df ["period"]

Comment: I like to help you. I will appreciate if you mark this post as a solution. Good luck!

Comment: I did use the CLI tools curl, sed and awk as you suggested.  I then used the first line from your panda solution  `df = pd.read_csv(newfile,names=["date","period"]+list(range(1,13)),index_col=[0,1],skiprows=day,nrows=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do what you are looking for:

[image]

And the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas a pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df.loc[df['a'] < 0.5, 'a'] = 1
```

[You can refer to this documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Added image showing how to access index:

[image]

Comment: I think I may be missing something, but using the example you have above, how do identify which row (index) contains say 0.249267 from the second table?  How do I find out it is 6?

Comment: You can get the index by accessing the index that is matching the condition like this `df[df['a'] <0.5].index`